# Use handlebars helper as function in javascript

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

I have a handlebars helper defined like this:

```js
Handlebars.registerHelper('isAdmin', function(input){
    return Meteor.user() && Meteor.user().admin;
});
```

and I'd like to use it elsewhere in my js as if it were a normal function. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a global function called `isAdmin` and then define your helper like this:

```js
this.isAdmin = function(input) {
  return Meteor.user() && Meteor.user().admin;
};

Handlebars.registerHelper('isAdmin', isAdmin);
```

Then you can use it anywhere in your templates like:

```js
Template.party.events({
  'submit': function() {
    if (isAdmin()) {
      return console.log('admin party!');
    }
  }
});
```